# After upgrading to Wordpress version 3.6, my homepage slider stopped auto-rotating

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider

After upgrading to Wordpress version 3.6, my homepage slider stopped auto-rotating, the superfish menu is overlapping and my background slider disappeared. All of the things are fine on underlying pages, which leads me to believe the problem is with the homepage slider code itself. ( http://www.thesavvybroker.com/ ) I've found the troublesome code ("slider.php") and have posted it below. I assume it needs to be updated to work properly with updated framework, however, I am a novice programmer, and all of my efforts to update the script have failed. At first I thought it was the && which I changed to OR, but that was not it. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $slider_timer = (ts_get_option('ts_slider_timer')=='off') ? 0 : ts_get_option('ts_slider_timer').'000'; ?>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#display").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'fast' } }).tabs('rotate', <?php echo $slider_timer; ?>, true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors that I can see.

Comment: @user2741231 There are errors, learn to use the built in JavaScript console in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

They removed the method, read the upgrade guide.

http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#removed-rotate-method

The docs say you would have to use this: https://github.com/cmcculloh/jQuery-UI-Tabs-Rotate to get it to work.